# Looking for a short story or essay - "At 80" written by a man at the end of his life about the experience of aging

Tags: identification-request, short-stories, essays

It's by a man in his 80's and he reflects on the experience of aging. I am almost positive the title was "At 80" but might have been "At Eighty" and might have had a subtitle. I don't recall the author being well-known. I'd estimate the story to be 10-15 pages.

From what I remember, it was in an anthology of stories for an English or Lit class. I think this was in high school, so '97ish to '01ish... but it could have been earlier. It may not have been published anywhere except this one textbook.

I remember the structure as being a series of musings and anecdotes (or perhaps snapshots or vignettes) from his life, going from his youth, into his middle age, and then as he came to be regarded by others as "old", though at first he didn't see himself that way.

One snippet recounted an argument where the author was approached by someone younger, ready to fight over bad driving. Upon seeing the author, the road rager lowered his fists, saying "Oh, you're just an old man."

There's also a metaphorical poem embedded in the story about a boy sledding downhill, aging as he goes. He sees friends and life events pass him by, the sled accelerating ever faster, the boy becoming older. It ends with the mental image of an old man riding off with his white hair flowing in the wind, his friends and family left behind.

It was really sad and profound and bittersweet and I've love to read it again. It affected me deeply as a teenager when most of these concepts were foreign to me. I've done some internet searching and can't seem to find it anywhere.

Comment: I thought of "On Turning Eighty" by Henry Miller, but he's not exactly unknown (and I don't think it had a poem in it)

Comment: @ClaraDiazSanchez Thanks, yes, that came up often in my Googling, but it isn't the story/essay I'm looking for. Thanks though.